# A point is randomly chosen from a $1\times1$ square. Find the probability that the distance between the point and the nearest diagonal is less than z

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

I have to solve the following problem:

If a point $(x_0 , y_0)$ is randomly chosen from a square, whose sides are equal to $1$, find the probability that the distance between the point and the nearest diagonal is less than z.

---

I have done the following:

We know that

$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0, (x,y) \notin [0,1]\times [0,1] \\
1, (x,y) \in [0,1]\times [0,1]
\end{matrix}\right.$

We want to calculate $P$("the distance between the point and the nearest diagonal is less than z")$=P(B_z)$

As we deduce that $z \in [0, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4})$, we've got the following cases:

- When $z=0$, as we are in an apex or in one of the diagonals, the distance is $0$.
- When $z \in (0, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4})$, the distance to the nearest diagonal would be $\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}\le z$

But what do I have to do now? I've tried to calculate the area of $B_z$ this way, but I don't know if I have to do it like this:

$Area(B_z)=\int_0^z \int_0^{\sqrt{z-(x-x_0)^2}+y_0}1 dydx$

Am I doing it ok? Or do I have to calculate something else?

Comment: It's probably simpler to divide the square into eight isosceles right triangles (by symmetry) and restrict to/condition on being in just one of those triangles. An additional simplification is to rotate one of those triangles so that its hypotenuse is horizontal, for then the distance to it is just the $y$-coordinate.

Comment: Looked at geometrically the region you're interested in is an X-shaped region inside the square. Just split the region into simple parts--the long arms, the stuff at the corners, the square at the center. It doesn't require an integral to compute this area.

Comment: So what do we have to change? the bounds of the integral? @GregMartin

Comment: and how can we do it without the integral? could you extend your answer, please? @JamieRadcliffe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This diagram shows the areas within distance $\frac{0.1}{\sqrt2}$ of the diagonals. Instead of calculating the area of the somewhat complicated X shape, you can calculate the area of the four right isosceles triangles that form the complement and subtract it from the total area $1$.

[image: area diagram]

Comment: Why do we have to calculate the area of the X shape? I mean, is that the probability we want to calculate?

Comment: @User160: I assumed that by "randomly chosen", you meant "uniformly randomly chosen". If so, by definition the probability of a uniformly randomly chosen point lying in a certain region is proportional to the area of that region; and since in this case the total area is $1$, the factor of proportionality in this case is $1$, so the probability is in fact equal to the area of the region.

Comment: but why exactly that area?

Comment: @User160: You want the probability that the distance of a point from the nearest diagonal is less than $z$ – that's a strip of width $z$ on either side of the diagonals. That's that shape.

Comment: Ah ok, so we have to calculate the area, depending on the parameter z, right?

Comment: @User160: Exactly.